# Datomic component ids

Tags: clojure, datomic

I want to transact a deeply nested tree structure into Datomic. An example data structure:

```
{:tree/id (d/tempid :db.part/user),
 :tree/nodes [
   {:node/name "Node1",
    :node/parent "root-node-ref",
    :node/tasks {"task-entities-map"}},
   {:node/name "Node2",
    :node/parent "node1-ref",
    :node/tasks {"task-entities-map"}}]}
```

Here Node2 is a child of Node1, and Node1 is a child of some root node.

Datomic docs at http://blog.datomic.com/2013/06/component-entities.html indicate that it's not necessary to specify temp ids for nested maps, as they will be created automatically (given that :db/isComponent is set to true for :tree/nodes, :node/tasks etc.).

The question is: how do i specify the parent-child relations here, as given by :node/parent attributes? I want to avoid having to specify node children e.g. by :node/children attribute. And will Datomic automatically specify temp ids for the entities in :node/tasks lists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user),
 :tree/nodes 
 [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user -1),
   :db/name "Node1",
   :node/parent (:db/id root-node)} ;; assuming you have queried root-node
  {:node/name "Node2",
   :node/parent (d/tempid :db.part/user -1)}]
```

Docstring of `d/tempid`:

> Within the scope of a single transaction, tempids map consistently to
>   permanent ids. Values of n from -1 to -1000000, inclusive, are
>   reserved for user-created tempids.

Find children of Node1 like this

```
 (d/q '[:find ?children
        :where [?node-1 :node/name "Node1"]
               [?children :node/parent ?node-1]] 
      (d/db conn))
```

Or, assuming that you have queried `node1`, find its children via

```
 (:node/_parent node1)
```

Comment: I am sorry, i've used the wrong name for the variable (sub-nodes) that must have confused you. Will change sub-nodes to say tasks and update the original question. 'tasks' are a list of entities that are not included in the original hierarchy. So that there are only :node/parents specified, but not :node/sub-nodes.

Comment: I have modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Had to correct tempid generation though, so that negative values are different for nodes and tasks.